# Ĉu oni atentu nur la „16 regulojn”?

Tags: grammar

William Auld en sia *La fenomeno Esperanto* skribis: Zamenhof starigis 16 regulojn, kiuj restas ĝis hodiaŭ la solaj devigaj reguloj.

Ĉu parolanto de Esperanto surbaze de tiu eldiro povas fajfi pri la bazaj gramatikoj, kiel PMEG kaj PAG kaj obei nur la [16 regulojn](ftp://ftp.stack.nl/pub/esperanto/introductions.dir/la-16-reguloj.txt)?

Answer (score 11):

Unue notindas, ke ekzistas ankaŭ Fundamentaj reguloj en la Ekzercaro, kiuj ne aperas inter la 16 reguloj de la gramatika parto de la Fundamento. Ekzemple en Ekzerco 30 estas skribite: "Aldonante al la vortoj montraj la vorton „ĉi”, ni ricevas montron pli proksiman". Ĉi tiaj reguloj el la Ekzercaro havas laŭ la Zamenhofaj ideoj pri la Fundamento la saman pezon kiel la 16 reguloj.

Krome notindas, ke la Zamenhofa kompreno pri "gramatiko" estis tre limigita kompare kun tio, kion modernaj lingvosciencistoj komprenas sub "gramatiko". Por li "gramatiko" estis tio, pri kio okupiĝis tradiciaj gramatikistoj, do ĉefe morfologio kaj kelkaj tre bazaj sintaksaj principoj, sed nenio simila al modernaj sintaksaj teorioj. Ĉion ekster tiu limigita kompreno de "gramatiko" li nomis "stilo". Kaj en la de li vortumita Bulonja Deklaracio, kiu oficialigis la Fundamenton de Esperanto, estas skribite: "Sed pro plena unueco de la lingvo al ĉiuj Esperantistoj estas rekomendate imitadi kiel eble plej multe tiun stilon, kiu troviĝas en la verko de la kreinto de Esperanto, kiu la plej multe laboris por kaj en Esperanto kaj la plej bone konas ĝian spiriton."

Do laŭ moderna kompreno de "gramatiko", kiu inkluzivas multon, kion li klasigis sub "stilo", ni certe ne povas fajfi pri detaloj de la gramatiko ne priskribitaj en Fundamentaj reguloj, sed ja ĝenerale imitu la Zamenhofan lingouzon, kaj verkoj kiel PMEG kaj PAG provas klarigi ankaŭ detalojn de tiu lingvouzo, kiuj ne estas klarigitaj en la Fundamentaj reguloj.

Laŭ la Zamenhofa kompreno, oni ne faras lingvan eraron, se oni ne sekvas Zamenhofan "stilon". Sed li tamen rekomendas sekvi tiun stilon, do oni ne povas fajfi pri ĝi.

Comment: Dankegon, Marcos. Cetere, por ke ĉio estu klara, ne mi celas fajfi pri detaloj de la gramatiko. Mi nur serĉis argumentojn kontraŭ tiuj, kiuj per la 16 reguloj provas pravigi ĉiajn erarojn!

Answer (score 4):

Kredeble, tio dependas de tio, kion oni celas. Certe parolantoj havas pli-malpli vastan gramatikan konon. Iuj volas havi nur rimedon por komuniki malformale, kaj aliaj ŝategas pasi horojn pri etaj gramatikaj detaloj kaj debati pri kie oni devas uzi komojn. Feliĉe, oni povas fari ambaŭ per Esperanto.

Vi jam donis la ĉefajn fontojn por tiuj, kiuj volas prizorgi detalan gramatikon, [Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/), [Plena Analiza Gramatiko](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plena_Analiza_Gramatiko) kaj oni povas ankaŭ konsulti la [Fundamento de Esperanto](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Fundamento_de_Esperanto), kaj [la Vikipedia artikolo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramatiko_de_Esperanto).